# Swift can't execute adb and command line instructions

Tags: android, swift, macos, shell

I'm trying to execute a command line instruction using swift in a macOS app.
Here is the code:

```
@discardableResult
static func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32
{
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

@discardableResult
static func shellAdb(_ args: String...) -> Int32
{
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

I use 'adb --v' and the 'echo hello' strings and pass it to the 'shell' function.

I've also tried the 'shellAdb' function for the first command but it doesn't work either.

If I use the 'shell' function, I get those errors:

```
env: adb --v: No such file or directory
env: echo 'hello': No such file or directory
```

The error code for both of them is '127'.

If I use the 'shellAdb' function I get this other error:

```
[General] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13
[General] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc5ab52cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffda8c048d objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc5b33c3d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fffc74de54e -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 3134
4   AndroidPaste                        0x0000000100003684 _TZFC12AndroidPaste17TerminalCommandEx8shellAdbftGSaSS__Vs5Int32 + 340
5   AndroidPaste                        0x0000000100002520 _TFC12AndroidPaste14ViewController11pasteActionfCSo8NSButtonT_ + 640
6   AndroidPaste                        0x000000010000269a _TToFC12AndroidPaste14ViewController11pasteActionfCSo8NSButtonT_ + 58
7   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffdb3d73a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
8   AppKit                              0x00007fffc3ca3721 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 456
9   AppKit                              0x00007fffc3787cc4 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
10  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3787bec __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
11  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffdb3d73a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
12  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3787b44 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 128
13  AppKit                              0x00007fffc37ca539 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 98
14  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffdb3d73a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
15  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3786426 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2481
16  AppKit                              0x00007fffc37ca272 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 798
17  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3784ddb -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 832
18  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3e1f24f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341
19  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3e1ba6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942
20  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3e1af0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541
21  AppKit                              0x00007fffc3c9f681 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145
22  AppKit                              0x00007fffc351a427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002
23  AppKit                              0x00007fffc34e4e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
24  AndroidPaste                        0x000000010000319d main + 13
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffdb1a5235 start + 1
```

The issue if in both shell and shellAdb functions, but they look like the examples I've found already.

I'm using Swift 3, macOS 10.12.5 and Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: The launchPath in your shellAdb  functions looks like a directory, not the (full) path to an executable, which it should be.

Comment: @MartinR that solves the problem using the 'shellAdb' function. I'd like to know why the 'echo hello' functions is returning a `127`error.

Answer (score -1):

Download last version of plateform tools with this link : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools?hl=fr

Extract the zip and add move adb file in your project.

you can load from the bundle :

```swift
let adb = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "adb", withExtension: nil)
```

next you can run commands with this method :

```swift
    private func runAdbCommand(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()
        
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", adb!.path + " " + command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
        task.launch()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return output
    }
```

If your wan't more details check this repository : https://github.com/naman14/adb-tools-mac/blob/master/adbconnect/AdbHelper.swift

He added adb file directly in the project to be able to execute adb commands.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34850034)

Comment: I just add new explications